# javacc - parsing tree + result

Tags: java, parsing, tree, javacc

How should look the code that after inserting one equation gives me a result and parsing tree? In my result user has to write the equation two times, because it uses two parsers, that share tokens. Here is the beginning of my code:

```
Calc parser = new Calc(System.in);
while (true)
{
  System.out.println("Input data:");
  try
  {
    System.out.print("Enter an expression like \"1+(2|3+3)*4|8;\" to generate tree :");
    Exp result = Calc.FinalTree();
    System.out.print("Enter an expression like \"1+(2|3+3)*4|8;\" to calculate:");
    String r2 = Calc.Final();
    /*Exp result = new Calc(new java.io.StringReader(args[0])).FinalTree();
    String r2 = new Calc(new java.io.StringReader(args[0])).Final();
    System.out.println(result);
    */
    System.out.println("Syntax is OK. \n Tree:" + result + "\n Calc value:" + r2);
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking at all.

Comment: Is there any way to solve it without writing the equation two times? As You can see, in my code you have to do it to get the result of equation and make parsing tree. Parsing tree uses the same tokens as my calculator. I'm looking for any ideas to make the parsing tree and calculate the equation after writing the input to console only ONE TIME. Idk, maybe converting the input... I don't know JavaCC very well.

Comment: Are you defining a `FinalTree` and a `Final` rule in your grammar? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Here's the whole code of calculator of rational numbers. It would be very hard to separate thoose parts. https://pastebin.com/QGF5qELk

Comment: It really wouldn't have been that hard to create a minimal version of that (just throw out everything except, say, addition and numbers and also delete the commented-out code and error handling and it's already a whole lot more compact), but fine.

Comment: If you really want to parse twice, read the input into a string.  Then parse the string twice. To parse the string: (a) create a StringReader, (b) instantiate the parser with the reader as argument, (c) call the main nonterminal's method.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you are defining two versions of every rule in your grammar: one version that creates an AST and one that calculates the result directly. Don't do that.

Instead you should only keep the versions that produce the AST and scrap the others. To evaluate the AST, you can then either add an `eval` method to your AST classes or use the visitor pattern. Then the code in your question could be written like this:

```
System.out.print("Enter an expression like \"1+(2|3+3)*4|8;\" to generate tree :");
Exp result = Calc.FinalTree();
String r2 = result.eval();
System.out.println("Syntax is OK. \n Tree:" + result + "\n Calc value:" + r2);
```

Or this:

```
System.out.print("Enter an expression like \"1+(2|3+3)*4|8;\" to generate tree :");
Exp result = Calc.FinalTree();
String r2 = new Evaluator().visit(result);
System.out.println("Syntax is OK. \n Tree:" + result + "\n Calc value:" + r2);
```